# silverlight client doesnt understand faultexception

Tags: silverlight, wcf, faultexception

I have a WCF service that throws an exception which I am trying to catch unsucessfully in my silverlight client code. I am using Undeclared Faults for Debugging purposes and this is my service method :

```
[OperationContract]
public ServiceResponse MyWCFServiceMethod()
{
  ServiceResponse resp = new ServiceResponse ();
  //code for setting resp...

  //purposely throw error here.
  throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("My fault Reason!")),new FaultCode("my fault code here"));
  return resp;
}
```

Now in my silverlight client view model, in the service's callback method, I try to handle it like this:

```
private void MyServiceCallback(MyWCFServiceMethodCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Error == null)
   {
       //proceed normally
   }
   else if (e.Error is FaultException)
   {
      FaultException<ExceptionDetail> fault = e.Error as FaultException<ExceptionDetail>;
      MessageBox.Show(fault.Detail.Message);
      MessageBox.Show(fault.Reason.ToString());
   }
}
```

at this line `else if (e.Error is FaultException)`  I still get System.Net.WebException {The remote server returned an error: NotFound.}

These are the config entries

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

This is the service class declaration

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MySilverlightWCFService
{
 ....
```

This service is in another project within the same silverlight solution.
Why is my silverlight client not able to get the fault exception I am throwing?

Thanks for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is probably throwing a HTTP 500 response code that Silverlight is ignoring. You must change the service to return a HTTP code that Silverlight will accept.

From [Data Performance and Fault Strategies in Silverlight 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee294456.aspx): (This article will show you how to return WCF faults to Silverlight.)

> **Infamous NotFound Error:** 
>   When the exception is raised, an HTTP
>   status
>   code of 500 is returned to
>   Silverlight. The browser networking
>   stack prevents Silverlight from
>   reading responses with a status code
>   of 500, so any SOAP fault information
>   contained within is unavailable to the
>   Silverlight client application. Even
>   if the message could be retrieved,
>   Silverlight 2 is not capable of
>   converting the fault back into a
>   managed exception. Both of these
>   issues have been addressed in
>   Silverlight 3.

Comment: so Silverlight was designed without service error handling in mind? :O

Comment: Looks like the status code must be changed from 500 to what Silverlight can read ..that too on the service side. So what if its a service that I have no control over? I think that is a lame workaround. Gonna read this one more time to see if I missed something!

Comment: I have done exactly what is mentioned in that article for handling Undeclared Faults; still getting the same error:'System.Net.WebException'.

Answer (score 7):

ok so finally what seems to be the way to make this work is to get one line of code added to the service just before you throw the fault exception!

```
System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
```

Then throw the actual exception:

```
throw new FaultException(new FaultReason(new FaultReasonText("My fault Reason!")),new FaultCode("my fault code here"));
```

Then in silverlight modify the service call back error handling section from what I put in my question above to:

```
   //else if (e.Error is FaultException)
   else
   {
      //FaultException<ExceptionDetail> fault = e.Error as FaultException<ExceptionDetail>;
      //MessageBox.Show(fault.Detail.Message);
      FaultException fault = e.Error as FaultException;
      MessageBox.Show(fault.Reason.ToString());
   }
```

That worked for me. Ugly way!

I will try with Declared faults when I get the time.

Comment: This is the actual solution. Dave's reply helped me get to it, so I credited his reply.

Comment: Hello, I was banging my head with the wall until I found your question and your solution worked like magic! Can you please explain what this line is doing? `System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;`

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [SilverlightFaultBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844556%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It will handle changing the status code for you.